# Docker compose two simple apps

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two apps: api and web. Both have their `dockerfile` and if I'm building them separately works fine. But now I'm trying to create `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  web-api:
    build: ./RatesApi
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
  web:
    build: ./Rates
    ports:
     - "8081:8081"
```

`docker-compose build` builds images and `docker-compose up` gives:

```
web-api_1  | Hosting environment: Production
web-api_1  | Content root path: /app
web-api_1  | Now listening on: http://[::]:80
web-api_1  | Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
web_1      | Hosting environment: Production
web_1      | Content root path: /app
web_1      | Now listening on: http://[::]:80
web_1      | Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

nothing on my wanted 8080 and 8081 ports, and **Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page** on port 80.

Can someone help me create correct `docker-compose.yml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app listening internally on port 80, you must write :

ports:
 - "8080:80"

and

ports:
 - "8081:80"

Comment: Then access the app at `http://localhost:8080` and `http://localhost:8081` respectively.

Comment: Read about [port mapping and port publishing](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/) please.

Comment: I had readed, but in a docker-compose file, the format for port mapping is : "$EXTERNAL_PORT:$INTERNAL_PORT"